# error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element when i put tabs Android

Tags: java, android, tabs

In my `.xaml` page code of my activity I want to put `tabs` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hakslogin.LoginSuccess" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_childform"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Child Form" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_childform"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#003EFF"
        android:text="Child" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I am getting error below:

```
error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element
```

How do I resolve it, kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: How do I put tabs on my `.xaml` pages and when i click on each tab xaml view changed, How can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An XML document can only have one root element**. You have more such elements. You should enclose your elements inside a single root layout, such as a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- All elements here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And your layout should be like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hakslogin.LoginSuccess" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_childform"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_backlogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Child Form" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_childform"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#003EFF"
        android:text="Child" />

    </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Use the `xmlns` attribute only once in your `xml page` will solve your problem.

Comment: TextView elements already in relativeLayout, my problems is that I want to pu tabs on my `.xaml` page.

Comment: not only the text view all the elements in your xml should be inside a root layout,xmlns you can use only once in your xml.

Comment: kindly try to make it understand, you put multiple times `RelativeLayout`

Comment: see my edited answer, still your unable to understand the problem, go and study this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: its k, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below from your relative layout and try

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```